# FullCalendar object with duplicate values...events displayed once though

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Despite searching through all "duplicate events" posts I have not found one similar to my issu...let me explain.

```
   render: function (close) {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      header: {  left: 'today,prev,next',  center: 'title',right: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth' },
      buttonText: {day: 'ημέρα', week: 'εβδομάδα', month: 'μήνας', today: 'σήμερα'},
      plugins: [ 'dayGrid','timeGrid','interaction','moment'], 
      nowIndicator: true,
      eventSources: ['closedates.php' ],
     ...
      
      
    
    });
```

As You see above I besides the standard event source...I use second one also(closedates.php)

```
if(!isset($holidays['noexist']))
    {
    $jsonholid=["id"=>'208',"editable"=>false,"description"=>"holiday","source"=>'closedates.php',"classNames"=>['holiday'],"title" => $holidays[0]['name'],"start" => $holidays[0]['date'],"end" =>$holidays[0]['date'],"backgroundColor"=>'#f48024'];
    array_push($events, $jsonholid);
    
    }

   
    }    
    echo json_encode($events);
```

what the above code does is to search through the DB if there ara holidays(shown) or the business users has entered in the app days closed(not shown for reasons of brevity).
In both cases JSON response is created with an allday event that may span from one day(if it is some -day holiday) or more(summer vacation)

The JSON when there is one day holiday is like that

```
[{"id":"208","editable":false,"description":"holiday","source":"closedates.php","classNames":["holiday"],"title":"\u039a\u03b1\u03b8\u03b1\u03c1\u03ac \u0394\u03b5\u03c5\u03c4\u03ad\u03c1\u03b1","start":"2021-03-15","end":"2021-03-15","backgroundColor":"#f48024"}]
```

And now the problem:
when the calendar initial load it displayes one event(only one in the DB)...so the event object which I access through eventRender has one element in it.[image]

IF I go to the next week in which there is a holiday the problem appears...despite event rendered once the event object contains two identical elements...corresponding to that holiday:[image]
If I go to the next week...another holiday-PROBLEM DOES NOT APPEAR.
iF i go back to the non holiday event(first image) the problem appears again[image]
On intiali loading the problem did not appear...but after changing week and loading the holiday from the secondary event source the non-holiday event is affected

So to recap...after the above..the non-holiday event AND the first holiday encountered during change week
appear to be evetns with ident values(the event object contains 2 ident elements)..despite being rendered properly
Somehow these 2 events tangle with each other...

Take a look also this schematic [schematic of problem](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjCBrCpLQye-iFMbPsVyv0oudCSv?e=qVUbEk)

I hope I get some advice cause I cannot find a solution.

Comment: `As You see above I besides the standard event source...I use second one also`...the code you've shown only defines one events source - `eventSources: ['closedates.php' ]`. No other event source is defined. It's unclear what you mean by "standard event source" or where you think it is defined?

Comment: `what the above code does is to search through the DB`..no it doesn't, it just creates one array entry and then encodes it to JSON. Are you describing some code which you haven't actually shown us?

Comment: We also can't see your eventRender code either, to see what you're logging, and how. And we can't see the actual JSON being returned by the server in that second-week situation either. Maybe it has two events in it? It's impossible for us to know since we can't really see the full code which generates it, or the data the server really returned. As far as I can tell, all you showed us is the data it generates when it's working correctly? But even then I'm not completely sure, from the way you've described it.

Comment: We have no idea what's really going on because your description doesn't match your code, and there is information missing. So it's quite difficult to help. Can you clarify the situation please?

Comment: give some time to describe the problem more clear...thanks

Comment: https://codepen.io/deoman12/pen/xxRyePe?editors=0011 eventDidmount(line 11) fires twice for the same event...an event with the name kkk date 10/3...sorry for the greek...this is what I do not understand

Comment: I think it's because your event source doesn't filter events by date - for example when you first load the calendar, it already returns those two events "clean monday" and "test" from the event source, but it does not mount them immediately because they don't fit into the current calendar. Then when you move to the following week, it fetches the events from the event source and downloads them again. So now there are 4 events, but they are copies. Yet it remembers the two earlier ones and also mounts them. Confusingly if you call calendar.getEvents() though it only returns 2.

Comment: This demo shows what I mean: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWNOybv?editors=1010 . So anyway I think a) there is maybe small bug in fullCalendar where it mounts events that it should have discarded, but also b) your server-side code is wrong because it should use the `start` and `end` dates which fullCalendar provides in order to only return events which occur between those dates. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed documents the fact that fullCalendar sends these parameters in each request, and expects your server to use them.

Comment: this is the code in the server https://pastebin.com/UBvKj1Tc ) ...so filtering does take place...so I do not think this is the probelm
if it is a bug..what do you think I should do..it does not  create much  problem..in this link (https://codepen.io/deoman12/pen/xxRyePe?editors=0011) a tooltip is attached to each event.(code inside eventDidmount)..despite eventDidmount firing twice the number of events

I suppose mount DOES NOT EQUAL render...causing the events come from the server..eventDidmount fires but they are not rendered in the calendar-the duplicates I mean.

Thanks